# Remove column padding in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two columns like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        hello
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the hellos to be right next to each other on screens of medium (md) or smaller. So essentially, it should look as though I'm not using any columns.

How would I accomplish this? I've already experimented with the `.no-gutters` class but that only removes a little padding. I also tried setting the padding and margin of both columns to zero and that also had very little effect.

Comment: What kind of effect are you trying to accomplish? If you do not want them to be right next to each other you could put the hello's in the same column. Or not use bootstrap classes for this?

Comment: `no-gutters` removes *all* the spacing between columns. do you have a demo/snippet that shows otherwise?

Comment: @Zim, here https://codepen.io/gabenotgave/pen/xxdxNrM

Comment: Still, **there is no padding on the columns** which is evident when you put a border on the columns: https://codeply.com/p/KeqP48QVcx . Of course, the content doesn't take the width of the entire columns. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="col-6 p-0 p-md-3"></div>
```

Comment: Pretty much has the same effect as the `.no-gutters` class